# Functional requirements and release criteria

Tags: metrics

What are the pros and cons of putting functional requirements into release/exit/ship criteria?

Comment: The answer is going to be 'it depends'.
I've worked on projects that were full of all sorts of release criteria and others that basically had none apart from 'release the latest build on Friday' What sort of answer were you looking for and what problem are you trying to solve by asking this question?

Comment: In some ways yes, since I have based Acceptance Tests on specific functionality being present, or in the case of a Sprint the sashime was the functionality.  Echoing Phil a little bit, are you trying to answer a question on functional requirements are not release criteria in your organization or are you planning ahead?

Comment: I was trying to figure out whether it is a good idea to keep functional reqs in my release criteria document. Of course, different people may have different answers, but it is still valuable to hear their recommendations

Answer (score 2):

In our organizations, functional requirements are usually too detailed to list each one as separate or specific release criteria.

Functional requirements usually stem from user stories or scenarios, so we might list all user stories / scenarios pass as part of our exit criteria.

Exit criteria is usually derived from high level data points (quantitative) that are critical factors for success in the marketplace, as well as a qualitative assessment of the product and other information.